# Executing simple Struts application using DAO

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I have created a one simple application using struts with dao. My application directory structure is exactly what is [here.](http://www.java4s.com/struts-tutorials/struts-2-hello-world-program/)

Web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Test4</display-name>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<include file="struts-default.xml"/>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" >

<action name="loginverify" class="com.java.files.AuthenticateUser" method="validateUser">
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="failure">login.jsp</result>       
</action>  

</package>
</struts>
```

Login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<div >

<center>
<h1>MITOSIS TECHNOLOGY</h1>
<H2>EMPLOYEE LOGIN</H2>
<s:form action="loginverify" method="post">
<s:textfield name="user.username" label="USER NAME" />
<s:password name="user.password" label="PASSWORD" />
<s:submit value="login" />
</s:form>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Action class:

```
package com.java.files;

import com.java.dao.UserDao;
import com.java.daoimpl.UserDaoImpl;
import com.java.model.User;

public class AuthenticateUser {

  private User user;
  public User getUser() {
  return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
}

private UserDao userdao;

public UserDao getUserdao() {
  return userdao;
}

public void setUserdao(UserDao userdao) {
  this.userdao = userdao;
}

public String execute(){
  return "success";
}

public String validateUser(){

  userdao=new UserDaoImpl();        
  User u=userdao.select_user(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword());
  if(u.getPassword().length()==0|| u.getUsername().length()==0 ){
  return "failure";
}
  else return "success";
}

public String createUser(){
  userdao=new UserDaoImpl();
  userdao.insert_user(user);
  return "success";
}
}
```

This is table structure:

```
create table user(usr_name varchar(50),password (20))
```

Model class:

```
package com.java.model;

public class User {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }
  public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

}
```

Sqlmap user.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap>

  <resultMap class="com.java.model.User" id="select_user_result">
    <result property="username" column="usr_name"/>
    <result property="password" column="password"/> 
  </resultMap>

  <insert id="insert_user" parameterClass="com.java.model.User">
    insert into user(usr_name,password) values(#username#,#password#)
  </insert>

  <select id="select_user" resultMap="select_user_result">
    select * from user where usr_name=#username# and password=#password#
  </select>

</sqlMap>
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

  <!--  
    Define the project's application context file(s) here.

    By default, the bean definitions can be overridden by
    registering a different definition with the same name. 
    --> 


 <bean id="AuthenticationAction" scope="prototype" class="com.java.files.AuthenticateUser">
 <property name="userdao" ref="userdao">

 </property>    

  </bean> 

  <bean id="AuthenticateDaoImplementation" class="com.java.daoimpl.UserDaoImpl">

  </bean> 

  <bean name="User" class="com.java.model.User" scope="prototype"/>

</beans>
```

SqlMapConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
  <settings
    cacheModelsEnabled="true"
    statementCachingEnabled="true"/>
  <sqlMap resource="sqlmap/User.xml"/>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

DaoImplementation:

```
package com.java.daoimpl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.java.dao.UserDao;
import com.java.model.User;

import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport;

public class UserDaoImpl extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements UserDao{

  @Override
  public void insert_user(User u) {
  System.out.println(u.getPassword());
  getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("insert_user", u);
}

  @Override
public User select_user(String name, String password) {

  Map <String, String>m= new HashMap <String,String>();
  m.put("username", name);
  m.put("password", password);
  return (User)getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("select_user", m);

  }

}
```

I dont know what is the problem in this code. When I set break point and validateuser method it goes to *daoImplementation* class but while executing return  `(User)getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("select_user", m);` code it raise `classnNotFoundException`. I dont know what problem present. Since I am new to struts I am not sure about *applicationContext.xml* and *sqlMap.xml* file are actually correct. I have stick with that problem over 3 days.

root cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SqlMapClient specified
org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:164)
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:242)
com.java.daoimpl.UserDaoImpl.select_user(UserDaoImpl.java:26)
com.java.files.AuthenticateUser.validateUser(AuthenticateUser.java:70)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
```

Comment: where is your userdaoimpl.java class?.just post that also,it would be helpful

Comment: Post a stacktrace with the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aslo configure `sqlMapClient` in Spring Container

```
<beans>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/sqlmap-config.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

And in your DAO did you specified it as property?

```
<bean id="AuthenticateDaoImplementation" class="com.java.daoimpl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"/>
</bean>
```

In `Sqlmap user.xml`:

Specify `namespace="User"`

```
<sqlMap namespace="User">
...
```